# Power BI: Clustered Column Chart with new customers

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have a Clustered Column Chart on which I want to compare 2022 against 2023:

[image]

What I want is?

1. Having the month column close to one each other
2. I have a list of new customers in 2023 and I want them to be shown on the column in yellow like this:

[image]

I have identified the new customers, they are 6. Should I create a column with `0` and `1` to identify them or is there a way to make them appear on the 2023 column with a filter?

Comment: You're asking for a clustered and stacked column chart which is not possible with native visuals. You can do this in Deneb custom visual though (free and certified but requires learning)

Comment: Thank you, good to know that what I'm trying to do is not doable. If you post it as a reply I will upvote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a *clustered* and *stacked* column chart which is not possible with native visuals. This can be done using the Deneb custom visual though (free and certified but requires learning).

Comment: Thank you @Davide, this community was missing you. In fact I was thinking about changing job.

Comment: You always crack me up Francesco :D